# C++ embbeded platform readability for division of 2 integer constants

Tags: c++, embedded

I have the following codes:

```
int foo = SamplingSomeValue();
int threshold = foo * 7 / 10;
...
```

which means that, the algorithm sampled some value, and set 70% of the sampled value as the lower-bound threshold, to find those similar values.

However, the constant `7/10` is ugly.   It's more readable by replacing it with `tRatio`, where `tRatio` is defined as `constexpr float tRatio = 0.7;`.  However, it's not efficient in embedded processors without floating point arithmetic hardware unit.

It's obvious that we can not write `constexpr int tRatio = (7/10);`, since it is 0.

What is the best way to maintain both efficiency and readability?

Comment: `inline int computeRatio(int x) { return x * 7 / 10; }`

Comment: Would a macro work? `#define tRatio 7 / 10`

Comment: @MotKohn Not that great idea. At least there should be some parenthesis.

Comment: @MotKohn, constant expression definition without parenthesis is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't really see where you are coming from with the claim that `foo * 7 / 10` is unreadable

Comment: Ok, it's not readability but manageability.   There are many of these constants, which I want to gather them together, in some header file, so that we know how many parameters our algorithm can change, and where to change it. Not just let them scatter around different places.

Comment: Watch out for undefined behaviour  (`foo * 7` may cause integer overflow)

Comment: Besides, if I have to use the ratio more than once, bare `*7/10` is not good,

Comment: I would go with `int threshold = foo * tPercent / 100;` and `#define tPercent 70`

Comment: It would seem that the magic number `10` is only there to give some precision to the division. Is that true? If so, then the same expression could be written as `10 * foo / CONSTANT` which is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For both readability and maintainability you might define a `cFraction` class that *includes*:

```
class cFraction
{
    public:
        cFraction( int num, int den ) : m_num(num), m_den(den){ }
        int operator*( int rhs ) const
        {
            return (rhs * m_num) / m_den ;
        }

    private:
        int m_num ;
        int m_den ;
} ;
```

And a non-member overload:

```
int operator*( int lhs, const cFraction& rhs )
{
    return rhs * lhs ;  // Multiply is commutative, 
                        // swap operands to use member overload
}
```

Then given:

```
const cFraction SEVENTY_PERCENT( 7, 10 ) ;
```

you can write:

```
int threshold = foo * SEVENTY_PERCENT ;
```

or:

```
int threshold = SEVENTY_PERCENT * foo ;
```

Of course while that provides readability, given the rather generic name you are kind of compelled perhaps to complete the class with a full set of overloads and type conversions to make `cFraction` look like a complete arithmetic type.  That may indeed be useful in other situations, but you could avoid that perhaps by implementing only the above and naming it something like `cIntegerRatio` to make it clear that this class has a very specific purpose and that only multiplication by an integer makes any sense.

Comment: Note that this is an idea not a recommendation - it depends how much trouble you think it is worth.

Comment: In fact, I did implemented a rational number class,  i.e. `p/q` where `p`, `q` are integers.  Not quite sure if it is a good way, since I always forget the order of numerator and denominator.  i.e. which comes first.  Ya. my Rational == your Fractional

Comment: I can't fix it if you don't tell me why it was down-voted.

Comment: someone else did that.  In fact, I like this one. So I upvote one for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an important consideration to make.

The statement regarding

> [...] embedded processors without floating point arithmetic hardware unit [...]

indicates that any division or modulo operation in your code is compiled into a function-call (the function is typically a part of a library provided to you along with the processor software development kit).

If you are to perform this `foo * 7 / 10` operation many times, then I would recommend to take some coding-optimization measurements.

For example: `foo * 11 / 16`, which the compiler can then interpret as `foo * 11 >> 4`.

The higher you choose the numerator, the higher are the chances for a better accuracy:

- `foo * 11 / 16`
- `foo * 22 / 32` no improvement from the previous
- `foo * 44 / 64` no improvement from the previous
- `foo * 89 / 128`
- `foo * 179 / 256`
- `foo * 358 / 512` no improvement from the previous
- `foo * 716 / 1024` no improvement from the previous
- `foo * 1443 / 2048`
- `foo * 2867 / 4096`
- ...

The downside of course, is that the multiplication can overflow.

In order to decide which factor to use, you need to consider:

- The size of the type of `foo` on your platform (`sizeof *foo`)
- The maximum value that `foo` can retain during any execution of your program

Comment: Since "efficiency" was mentioned in the question this answer is somewhat relevant - although the requirement was to "maintain" efficiency not necessarily *improve* it.  Lack of hardware floating point however does not imply lack of hardware integer divide although many low-end processors do lack such an instruction and for those that have one it typically requires more cycles than most other instructions - but not nearly so much as software floating point.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is,

```
#define FRAC 7/10
#define DIV(x) (x)*FRAC
...
int  threshold = DIV(foo)
```

If you ensure that `FRAC` is only used in the `DIV` macro then, you can dispense with the brackets in the definition for `FRAC` (as an exception, in this case) and use the `DIV` macro inside your code.

Comment: Which of the three pairs of "brackets" (or more correctly parentheses) are you suggesting may be omitted?  I cannot see how any of them are unnecessary in any usage constraint. In particular you need the parentheses in the macro definition in case x is an expression, otherwise `DIV (90 + 10)` for example will expand to `90 + 10 * 10 / 7` and yield `104` instead of the required `70`. In other cases they are syntactically necessary.  `DIV` is perhaps an inappropriate and confusing name.

Comment: In the normal case, there would be brackets around the definition for `FRAC`. i.e. `#define FRAC (7/10)` as per normal practice. However, these brackets would result in incorrect order of execution and the result of OP's original question would be 0. This solution does not use the brackets around `FRAC`, but `FRAC` is used in only one place, and so control can be maintained.

Comment: I see what you mean, but that is entirely unclear in your answer. You it reads as if you are referring to a modification to your example; you cannot "dispense" with something that was not there in the first instance. Moreover since `FRAC` is then *only* of use in this situation, it would be better tot to define it at all and rather use `#define SEVENTY_PERCENT_OF(x) ((x)*7/10)`. Also the use of a macro is a very C-oriented solution, and usually best avoided.

Comment: The answer was amended to make clear that the bracket in FRAC was mentioned. This was in reference to the question where OP rightly mentioned (7/10) is 0, and asked for a solution removing the brackets around them. Also OP is working in embedded, and so gave a macro solution, which might be best resource wise.

Comment: I disagree that it is clarified; *"you can dispense with the brackets..."* suggests (in fact *means*) that they are there in the example but that it does not matter whether they are there or not.  In fact it is important that they are *not* there.  You should perhaps say *"the omission of the parentheses around the macro definition for `FRAC` is intentional and necessary to the correct operation of `DIV`.  But you have entirely disregarded my suggestion that the definition of `FRAC` in the in any case is unnecessary - if it is only used in `DIV` it serves no purpose at all.

Comment: You also missed my point about what `(...)` are called: `()` = parentheses, `[]` = brakets, `{}` = braces; since all three are used in C++ it is useful to be accurate.